# unmarshalling SOAP response with spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm trying to call a soap ws exposed with SpringWS:
below you can find:

-applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="com.al.factories" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="WebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"></property>
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"></property>
        <property name="messageSender">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender" />
        </property>
        <property name="defaultUri"
            value="http://localhost:8080/web_services/hello" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="yourServiceClient" class="com.al.client.YourServiceClient">
        <property name="webServiceTemplate" ref="WebServiceTemplate" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

-ObjectFactory.java

```
package com.al.factories;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;

import com.al.wsmapping.InputParameters;
import com.al.wsmapping.Job;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    public InputParameters createYourRequest() {
        return new InputParameters();
    }

    public Job createYourResponse() {
        return new Job();
    }

}
```

-InputParameters.java

```
package com.al.wsmapping;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
//@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "paramONE" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "getJoboolone", namespace = "http://ws.mkyong.com/")
public class InputParameters {
}
```

-YourServiceClient.java

```
package com.al.client;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;

import com.al.factories.ObjectFactory;
import com.al.wsmapping.InputParameters;
import com.al.wsmapping.Job;

@Component("yourServiceClient")
public class YourServiceClient implements YourService {

    private static final ObjectFactory WS_CLIENT_FACTORY = new ObjectFactory();

    @Autowired
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    public String getValue() {
        InputParameters request = WS_CLIENT_FACTORY
                .createYourRequest();

        Job response = (Job) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);

        System.out.println(response.getJobName());

        return response.toString();
    }
```

I define a simple client to test it, with a main method , calling them with SpringWS, It works but I'm anable to unmarshall the response. I know I should do something with xml mapping but I don't know how do it.
My WS method is without parameters.
if someone could give me some suggestions it would be valued!
I found so many examples, but no one suits my needs...
Below you can see my request and response with SOAPUI, as you can see, the backend service works as expected.

-SOAPUI REQUEST

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.mkyong.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:getJoboolone/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

-SOAPUI RESPONSE

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:getJobooloneResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.mkyong.com/">
         <return>
            <jobId>30</jobId>
            <jobName>Dev presso Accenture</jobName>
            <jobRole>Developer</jobRole>
            <salary>3000</salary>
            <type>Omnesciente</type>
            <userId>
               <password>ererer</password>
               <userId>1</userId>
               <userName>ivoru84</userName>
            </userId>
         </return>
      </ns2:getJobooloneResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

-STACKTRACE

```
giu 05, 2016 2:31:43 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFORMAZIONI: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@238e0d81: startup date [Sun Jun 05 14:31:43 BST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
giu 05, 2016 2:31:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMAZIONI: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
giu 05, 2016 2:31:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFORMAZIONI: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1554909b: defining beans [messageFactory,marshaller,WebServiceTemplate,yourServiceClient]; root of factory hierarchy
giu 05, 2016 2:31:43 PM org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory afterPropertiesSet
INFORMAZIONI: Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
giu 05, 2016 2:31:43 PM org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller createJaxbContextFromContextPath
INFORMAZIONI: Creating JAXBContext with context path [com.al.factories]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:543)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:384)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:378)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:370)
    at com.al.client.YourServiceClient.getValue(YourServiceClient.java:23)
    at com.al.maintest.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:16)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsConnection.onSendAfterWrite(HttpComponentsConnection.java:119)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:47)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:622)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:585)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
    ... 5 more
```

thank you in advance!
A.d.

Comment: Your set up is looking okay to me You can turn on the spring  web service logging  and should be able to trace through request and response and see where exactly its breaking and then we can narrow down our efforts to that area.

Comment: I add the stacktrace above in the question...as you can see it goes in Read timed out and the stack trace is not talking as it should! Do you know how I can resolve or how I can improve the stack trace as you told me?thks

Comment: you can try removing timeout for now. Definitely not a solution for production but just to debug this issue. Also, check the server logs too. <bean id="messageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value=0>
        <property name="readTimeout" value=0>
</bean>